# Why does not this AlertDialog show?

Tags: android

I created an `AlertDialog` :

```
public class MessageDialogView extends AlertDialog {

    private Context ctxt;
    private View contenu, titleBar;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public MessageDialogView(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        super(context);
        ctxt = context;
        contenu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.msg_dialog, null);
        titleBar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_title, null);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setCustomTitle(titleBar);
        setView(contenu, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, ctxt.getResources().getString(R.string.button_ok), new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    public void setTitre(String titre) {
        if (titre != null)
            ((TextView)titleBar.findViewById(R.id.titre)).setText(titre);
    }
    public void setMsg(String text){
        if (text != null)
            ((TextView)contenu.findViewById(R.id.msgText)).setText(text);
    }

}
```

The xml `layout` are very simple ( not necessary to copy their code here :) )

When I try to show the `AlertDialog` then nothing is showing : just the screen is darkened !

```
public class SyncActivity extends Activity {

    private RadioButton webVersMobile = null;
    private MessageDialogView dlg = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.syncro);
        webVersMobile = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.webMobile);
        dlg = new MessageDialogView(SyncActivity.this, getLayoutInflater());
    }
    ...
    public void displayError(String msg) {
        dlg.setTitre(getString(R.string.titreErrMsgBox));
        dlg.setMsg(msg);
        dlg.show();
    }
    ...
}
```

I call the dialog like this :

```
private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> { 

        ...

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... s_url) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (error) {
                displayError(result);
            } else {

            }
        }

        private void displayError(String msg) {
            dlg.setTitre(getString(R.string.titreErrMsgBox));
            dlg.setMsg(msg);
            dlg.show();
        }
    }
```

So what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: Where do you call the dialog?

Comment: @pheromix, and your private Async class is inside the SyncActivity file ?

Comment: yes the Async class is inside the SyncActivity class .

Comment: Ok try this, make your `private MessageDialogView dlg = null;` to static like `private static MessageDialogView dlg = null;` and then try again.

Comment: @pheromix, did you try making it `static` ?

Comment: yes but same problem !

Comment: are you sure `error` is `true` ?

Comment: yes because I used Toast to display text !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72819/discussion-between-kedarnath-and-pheromix).

Comment: You should extends `DialogFragment`, which is container for all kind if `Dialog`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , I found that the reason of my error is that I implemented the `onCreate` method. When I removed the implementation then the Dialog is shown :)

```
public class MessageDialogView extends AlertDialog {

    private View contenu, titleBar;

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    public MessageDialogView(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        super(context, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
        contenu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.msg_dialog, null);
        titleBar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_title, null);
        setCustomTitle(titleBar);
        setView(contenu, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, context.getResources().getString(R.string.button_ok), new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    public void setTitre(String titre) {
        if (titre != null)
            ((TextView)titleBar.findViewById(R.id.titre)).setText(titre);
    }
    public void setMsg(String text){
        if (text != null)
            ((TextView)contenu.findViewById(R.id.msgText)).setText(text);
    }

}
```

Comment: I removed the Override of `onCreate` of the Alertdialog , and I copied the setCustomTitle and setView inside the constructor !

Comment: I did the same, but it is still showing me a trimmed alertdialog, like I shown you in the pic.

Comment: I copied the `setCustomTitle` and `setView` inside the constructor of MessageDialogView !

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `show()`  method to display the dialog.

```
dlg = new MessageDialogView(SyncActivity.this, getLayoutInflater());
```

After this line write `dlg.show();` in `onCreate()` method.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier, When I wrote this answer that time, he hasn't uploaded that calling code.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier, perhaps you may take your -1 vote back now ?